# Edditing .json with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a php script which adds a file called results.json, into my online server, wherever the php script is located;

```
<?php 
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from Posts limit 20"); 

    $response = array();
    $posts = array();
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $title=$row['title']; 
        $url=$row['url']; 

        $posts[] = array('title'=> $title, 'url'=> $url);

    } 

    $response['posts'] = $posts;

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
    fclose($fp);


?>
```

What I want to do is; edit the results.json file, or add to its containing, rather than creating a new one every time. What do you suggest?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  The safest method is to load the whole thing into a PHP object, modify the data, and output it again.  But this can be slow if your file is huge.

Comment: 1) load json text from file 2) decode json text -> php structure 3) modify php structure 4) encode structure to json and write to file. You do **NOT** directly modify the raw JSON text. the slightest bug in your code will introduce a syntax error and kill the entire structure.

Comment: Can you give me a code example; to take and add to a JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this;

```
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('results.json'));
array_push($json_data, 'some value');
file_put_contents('results.json', json_encode($json_data));
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for this would be to decode the JSON file back into an object and then add rows before rewriting

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("results.json"));
$response['posts'][] = array(...);
$fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);
```